# Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'PropDecoratorFactory' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, import, module, decorator

I'm building a simple AngularJS 2/s app, and I try to pass a variable from a nested child component to the parent component, so the parent can change it, like so:

Child:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-copm-player',
      templateUrl: './copm-player.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./copm-player.component.css']
    })
    export class CopmPlayerComponent implements OnInit {
      // @Input('isRoundStart') isRoundStart: boolean = false;
      isRoundStart: boolean = false;
      // @Input('RandNum') randNums = 0;
      randNums = 0;
      constructor() { }
      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

Parent:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input} from '@angular/core';
    import {CopmPlayerComponent} from './copm-player/copm-player.component';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-players-board',
      templateUrl: './players-board.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./players-board.component.css'],

    })
    export class PlayersBoardComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild(CopmPlayerComponent) compPlayer: CopmPlayerComponent;
      onStartRound(){
        console.log(this.compPlayer.isRoundStart);
        
        this.compPlayer.isRoundStart = true;
        console.log(this.compPlayer.isRoundStart);
        
      }
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

my IDE says there is no probem, but when I try to run the entire app I get this error messsage:

```
> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'PropDecoratorFactory' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1689)
    at compiler.es5.js:15373
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15356)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:26679)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26652)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26581)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (core.es5.js:4595)
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (core.es5.js:4581)
    at Object.107 (main.ts:10)
```

The wierd thing is I couldn't find any decorator name "PropDecoratorFactory", and I see no such decleration in app.module.ts:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { Output } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
    import { PlayersBoardComponent } from './players-board/players-board.component';
    import { PlayerComponent } from './players-board/player/player.component';
    import { ScoresComponent } from './players-board/scores/scores.component';
    import { CopmPlayerComponent } from './players-board/copm-player/copm-player.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        PlayersBoardComponent,
        PlayerComponent,
        ScoresComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ViewChild
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is? What can I do to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall remove ViewChild from list of imports in AppModule.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ViewChild <--- Remove this one
  ],
```